# Visual Studio 2019 Duplicating Code During Copy Paste

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am having some unusual behavior in **Visual Studio 2019**.  I have a **ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC project** where in the view I am copying and pasting a Kendo control inside a view.  As you can see below VS is duplicating the `source.Ajax()` call every time I copy and paste and found this happening.
  Any idea how to stop Visual Studio from doing this selective duplication?

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("ddlStates")
          .DataTextField("StateProvince")
          .DataValueField("ID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
          .OptionLabel("Select States")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
          source.Ajax()
          .Read(read =>
          {
              source.Ajax()
              .Read(read =>
              {
                  source.Ajax()
                  .Read(read =>
                  {
                      source.Ajax()
                      .Read(read =>
                      {
                          read.Action("GetStates", "Agent");
              });
          })
)
```

Originally the code I was copying was the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("ddlStates")
          .DataTextField("StateProvince")
          .DataValueField("ID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
          .OptionLabel("Select States")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Ajax()
              .Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetStates", "Agent");
              });
          })


)
```

Comment: It is duplicating the following every time I copy and paste. "source.Ajax()
          .Read(read =>
          {"

Comment: I do not understand.  If you're copy/pasting that segment of code, then yes, you'll end up with more than one copy of that code.

Comment: So everytime copy the entire control from top to bottom VS is inserting an extra section of code.

Comment: My first comment asked "what part of this code is being pasted" and you replied with a short segment of code in your comment.  Now you're saying you're pasting the entire thing from top to bottom.  So I'll ask again.  What was the code to start with?  What are you pasting?  Where are you pasting it?

Comment: What do you get when you paste in a blank text file?

Comment: When I copy the entire control in VS. VS inserts the control, but then it inserts a ADDITIONAL section of "source.Ajax().Read => {".  When I copy and paste the control into a text editor it does not do odd extra code insert.

Comment: Please edit the question with the contents of your clipboard, which is getting pasted into a text file correctly.  We need to be able to reproduce the issue, and to do that, we need to paste the same thing you are pasting.

Comment: I have updated the original post @Amy.  Thank you.

Comment: Okay... that is absolutely bizarre.

Comment: If you press undo (the button, or Ctrl-Z), it removes the additional text it inserted. But it's very weird.